# For comprehension: how to run Futures sequentially

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

Given the following methods...

```
def doSomething1: Future[Int] = { ... }
def doSomething2: Future[Int] = { ... }
def doSomething3: Future[Int] = { ... }
```

... and the following for-comprehension:

```
for {
  x <- doSomething1
  y <- doSomething2
  z <- doSomething3
} yield x + y + z
```

The three methods run in parallel, but in my case `doSomething2` MUST run after `doSomething1` has finished. How do I run the three methods in sequence?

**EDIT**

As suggested by [Philosophus42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393903/philosophus42), here below is a possible implementation of `doSomething1`:

```
def doSomething1: Future[Int] = {
  // query the database for customers younger than 40;
  // `find` returns a `Future` containing the number of matches
  customerService.find(Json.obj("age" -> Json.obj("$lt" -> 40)))
}
```

... so the `Future` is created by an internal call to another method.

**EDIT 2**

Perhaps I simplified the use case too much... and I'm sorry. Let's try again and go closer to the real use-case. Here are the three methods:

```
for {
  // get all the transactions generated by the exchange service
  transactions <- exchange.orderTransactions(orderId)

  //for each transaction create a log
  logs <- Future.sequence(tansactions.map { transaction =>
    for {
      // update trading order status
      _ <- orderService.findAndUpdate(transaction.orderId, "Executed")

      // create new log
      log <- logService.insert(Log(
        transactionId => transaction.id,
        orderId => transaction.orderId,
        ...
      ))
    } yield log
  })
} yield logs
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a log for each transaction associated with an order. `logService.insert` gets invoked many times even if `transactions` just contains one entry.

Comment: Do you have a code sample that fails? Because the for comprehension should actually execute the Futures in sequences if they are not instantiated outside of the for{...}.

Comment: the `Future` is created by an internal call to another method... see my updated post.

Comment: j3d: Which methods exactly do you want **not** be executed in parallel? I'm irritated, as you mainly speak about number of invocations of `logService.insert`. Please try to give a working excerpt and / or give more information on what the methods are doing precisely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Comment on your post

First, how does the code inside `doSomethingX` look like? Even more irrated, that with your given code, the futures run parallel.

## Answer

In order to make the `Future` execution sequential, just use

```
for {
  v1 <- Future { ..block1... } 
  v2 <- Future { ..block2... } 
} yield combine(v1, v2)
```

The reason this works, is that the statement Future { ..body.. } starts asynchronous computation, at that point in time the statement is evaluated.

With the above for-comprehension desugared

```
Future { ..block1.. }
  .flatMap( v1 => 
     Future { ..block>.. }
       .map( v2 => combine(v1,v2) )
  )
```

it is obvious, that

- if `Future{ ...block1... }` has it's result available,
- the `flatMap` method is triggered, which
- then triggers execution of `Future { ...block2... }`.

Thus `Future { ...block2... }` is executed **after** `Future { ...block1... }`

## Additional information

A `Future`

```
Future { 
  <block> 
}
```

**immediately** triggers execution of contained block via the `ExecutionContext`

Snippet 1:

```
val f1 = Future { <body> }
val f2 = Future { <otherbody> }
```

The two computations are running parallel (in case your `ExecutionContext` is setup this way), as the two values are evaluated immediately.

Snippet 2:

The construct

```
def f1 = Future { ..... }
```

will start execution of the future, once `f1` is called

**Edit:**

j3d, I'm still confused, why your code does not work as expected, if your statement is correct, that the Future **is created within** the `computeSomethingX` methods.

Here is a code snippet that proves, that `computeSomething2` is executed after `computeSomething1`

import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
    import scala.concurrent.duration._

```
object Playground {

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def computeSomething1 : Future[Int] = {
    Future {
      for (i <- 1 to 10) {
        println("computeSomething1")
        Thread.sleep(500)
      }
      10
    }
  }

  def computeSomething2 : Future[String] = {
    Future {
      for(i <- 1 to 10) {
        println("computeSomething2")
        Thread.sleep(800)
      }
      "hello"
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val resultFuture: Future[String] = for {
      v1 <- computeSomething1
      v2 <- computeSomething2
    } yield v2 + v1.toString

    // evil "wait" for result

    val result = Await.result(resultFuture, Duration.Inf)

    println( s"Result: ${result}")
  }
}
```

with output

```
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething1
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
computeSomething2
Result: hello10
```

**Edit 2**

If you want them to be executed in **parallel**, create the futures beforehand (here `f1` and `f2`)

```
def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
  val f1 = computeSomething1
  val f2 = computeSomething2

  val resultFuture: Future[String] = for {
    v1 <- f1
    v2 <- f2
  } yield v2 + v1.toString

  // evil "wait" for result

  val result = Await.result(resultFuture, Duration.Inf)

  println( s"Result: ${result}")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much (see also my updated post for an example of how `doSomething1` might look like). Just a final question about performance... is there any remarkable overhead in passing a methods that returns a `Future` to `Future.apply` as suggested by you?

Comment: @j3d: See the new part in my answer.

Comment: See my second update to my post... I've added an example that's very close to my real use case.

Comment: Your answer is just OK and the methods are executed sequentially. Unfortunately the issue was in a call to a third party service - the problem was so tricky that it took me an entire day to find it. Thank u very much and don't be irritated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I see two variants to achieve this:

**First:**
Make sure that the Futures are created inside the for comprehension. This means your functions should be defined like this: `def doSomething1: Future[Int] = Future { ... }`. In that case the for comprehension should execute the Futures in sequence.

**Second:**
Use the map function of the Future that you need to complete before the others start:

```
doSomething1.map{ i =>
  for {
  y <- doSomething2
  z <- doSomething3
  } yield i + y + z
}
```